nav2 cmd_vel only has Theta values
i am trying to integrate nav2 on a real robot. So far i managed to generate maps using the slam toolbox and load them, it creates a costmap, the local costmap is updated and sees obstacles. A path is generated when i give a goal.
However, the cmd_vel i get always has x and y values at 0. Theta works fine though. I tried to tinker parameters but i can't find the problem.
I keep getting this warning : [controller_server-9] [WARN] [1716971520.474335648] [controller_server]: Control loop missed its desired rate of 5.0000Hz 
I don't know why the controller is being so slow and if that is related to my problem.
Here is my param file if you want to take a look :
bt_navigator parameters
bt_navigator:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
      global_frame: map
      robot_base_frame: /base_link
      odom_topic: "/odometry"
      bt_loop_duration: 10  
      default_server_timeout: 20
      # 'default_nav_through_poses_bt_xml' and 'default_nav_to_pose_bt_xml' are use defaults:
      # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_to_pose_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
      # nav2_bt_navigator/navigate_through_poses_w_replanning_and_recovery.xml
      # They can be set here or via a RewrittenYaml remap from a parent launch file to Nav2.
      qos_overrides:
        /clock:
          subscription:
            depth: 1
            durability: volatile
            history: keep_last
            reliability: best_effort
        /tf:
          subscription:
            depth: 100
            durability: volatile
            history: keep_last
            reliability: reliable
        /tf_static:
          subscription:
            depth: 100
            durability: volatile
            history: keep_last
            reliability: reliable
      transform_tolerance: 0.1

controller_server parameters
controller_server:
    ros__parameters:
      use_sim_time: False
      controller_frequency: 5. # Hz
      min_x_velocity_threshold: 0.001
      min_y_velocity_threshold: 0.001
      min_theta_velocity_threshold: 0.0003
      failure_tolerance: 0.0
      odom_topic: "odometry"
      scan.topic: "/scan"
      progress_checker: "progress_checker"
      controller_plugins: ["FollowPath"]
      goal_checker: ["goal_checker"]

      # Progress checker parameters
      progress_checker:
        plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleProgressChecker"
        required_movement_radius: 0.5
        movement_time_allowance: 10.0
      # Goal checker parameters
      goal_checker:
        plugin: "nav2_controller::SimpleGoalChecker"
        xy_goal_tolerance: 0.01
        yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.01
        stateful: True

      # basic MPC with DWB
      FollowPath:
        plugin: "dwb_core::DWBLocalPlanner"
        debug_trajectory_details: True

        # max speed according to constructor is 1.6m/s
        min_vel_x: -1.2
        min_vel_y: -1.2
        max_vel_x: 1.2
        max_vel_y: 1.2
        
        # angular velocity limits
        max_vel_theta: 0.3  
        min_speed_theta: -0.3

        # acceleration limits

        acc_lim_x: 0.4
        acc_lim_y: 0.4 
        decel_lim_x: -0.4
        decel_lim_y: -0.4 
        acc_lim_theta: 0.1
        decel_lim_theta: -0.1 

        # Goal Tolerance
        xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
        yaw_goal_tolerance: 0.25
        latch_xy_goal_tolerance: False

        # Forward Simulation parameters
        sim_time: 2.0
        vx_samples: 20
        vy_samples: 20
        vtheta_samples: 40

        # Trajectory scoring parameters
        linear_granularity: 1.
        angular_granularity: 0.025
        time_granularity: 1.0
        transform_tolerance: 2.0  # Tolerance for transform lookup
        xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25  # Tolerance for XY goal position
        trans_stopped_velocity: 0.0  # Velocity threshold for considering the robot as stopped
        short_circuit_trajectory_evaluation: True  # Enable short-circuiting of trajectory evaluation
        stateful: True  # Enable stateful behavior

        # critics parameters
        critics: ["RotateToGoal", "Oscillation", "BaseObstacle", "GoalAlign", "PathAlign", "PathDist", "GoalDist"]

        # Parameters for the BaseObstacle critic
        BaseObstacle.scale: 1.0

        # Parameters for the PathAlign critic
        PathAlign.scale: 1.0
        PathAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.5 # Point in front of robot to look ahead to compute angular change from.

        # Parameters for the PathDist critic
        PathDist.scale: 1.0

        # Parameters for the GoalAlign critic
        GoalAlign.scale: 1.0
        GoalAlign.forward_point_distance: 0.5 # Point in front of robot to look ahead to compute angular change from.

        # Parameters for the GoalDist critic
        GoalDist.scale: 1.0

        # Parameters for the RotateToGoal critic
        RotateToGoal.xy_goal_tolerance: 0.25
        RotateToGoal.trans_stopped_velocity: 0.0
        RotateToGoal.scale: 1.0
        RotateToGoal.slowing_factor: 5.0
        RotateToGoal.lookahead_time: -1.0

        qos_overrides:
          /clock:
            subscription:
              depth: 1
              durability: volatile
              history: keep_last
              reliability: best_effort

local_costmap parameters
local_costmap:
local_costmap:
  ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    global_frame: odom
    robot_base_frame: /base_link
    plugin_names: ["obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
    #plugin_types: ["nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer", "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"]
    rolling_window: true
    width: 10
    height: 10
    resolution: 0.005
    footprint: "[ [0.6, 0.195], [0.6, -0.195], [-0.6, -0.195], [-0.6, 0.195] ]"
    map_topic: '/map'
    inflation_layer:
      cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
      inflation_radius: 0.1
    obstacle_layer:
      enabled: True
      observation_sources: scan
      scan:
        topic: /scan
        sensor_frame: /scan
        min_obstacle_height: 0.0 #TODO
        max_obstacle_height: 100.0 #TODO
        clearing: True
        marking: True
        data_type: "LaserScan"
    always_send_full_costmap: True

    qos_overrides:
      /clock:
        subscription:
          depth: 1
          durability: volatile
          history: keep_last
          reliability: best_effort

global_costmap parameters
global_costmap:
global_costmap:
ros__parameters:
    use_sim_time: False
    update_frequency: 1.0
    publish_frequency: 1.0
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: /base_link
    rolling_window: true
    # todo robot_radius
    resolution: 0.05
    track_unknown_space: true
    plugins: ["static_layer", "obstacle_layer", "inflation_layer"]
    obstacle_layer:
      plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::ObstacleLayer"
      enabled: True
      observation_sources: scan
      scan:
        topic: /scan
        max_obstacle_height: 200.0 #TODO
        min_obstacle_height: 5.0 #TODO
        clearing: False
        marking: True
        data_type: "LaserScan"
        raytrace_max_range: 1.0 #TODO
        raytrace_min_range: 0.0 #TODO
        obstacle_max_range: 5.0 #TODO
        obstacle_min_range: 0.0 #TODO
    static_layer:
      plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::StaticLayer"
      map_subscribe_transient_local: True
      map_topic: "/map"
    inflation_layer: 
      plugin: "nav2_costmap_2d::InflationLayer"
      cost_scaling_factor: 1.0
      inflation_radius: 0.001
    always_send_full_costmap: True
    width: 100
    height: 100

    qos_overrides:
      /clock:
        subscription:
          depth: 1
          durability: volatile
          history: keep_last
          reliability: best_effort

planner_server parameters
planner_server:
ros__parameters:
    expected_planner_frequency: 20.0
    planner_plugins: ["GridBased"]

    qos_overrides:
      /clock:
        subscription:
          depth: 1
          durability: volatile
          history: keep_last
          reliability: best_effort
    use_sim_time: False

    # basic planning with A*
    GridBased:
      plugin: "nav2_navfn_planner/NavfnPlanner"
      tolerance: 0.5
      use_astar: True
      allow_unknown: True

smoother_server parameters
smoother_server:
ros__parameters:
    smoother_plugins: ["simple_smoother"]
    simple_smoother:
      plugin: "nav2_smoother::SimpleSmoother"
      tolerance: 1.0e-10
      max_its: 1000
      do_refinement: True
    use_sim_time: False
    transform_tolerance: 0.1

velocity_smoother parameters
velocity_smoother:
ros__parameters:
    /bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
    smoothing_frequency: 20.0
    scale_velocities: false
    feedback: "OPEN_LOOP"
    max_velocity: [1.2, 1.2, 0.3]
    min_velocity: [-1.2, -1.2, -0.3]
    deadband_velocity: [0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
    velocity_timeout: 1.0
    max_accel: [0.4, 0.4, 0.1]
    max_decel: [-0.4, -0.4, -0.1]
    odom_topic: "odom"
    odom_duration: 0.1
    velocity_timemout: 1.0
    use_sim_time: False

behavior_server parameters
behavior_server:
ros__parameters:
    /bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
    costmap_topic: local_costmap/costmap_raw
    footprint_topic: local_costmap/published_footprint
    cycle_frequency: 10.0
    behavior_plugins: ["spin", "backup", "drive_on_heading", "wait"]
    spin:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Spin"
    backup:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/BackUp"
    drive_on_heading:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/DriveOnHeading"
    wait:
      plugin: "nav2_behaviors/Wait"
    global_frame: map
    robot_base_frame: /base_link
    transform_tolerance: 0.1
    use_sim_time: False
    simulate_ahead_time: 2.0
    max_rotational_vel: 1.0
    min_rotational_vel: 0.4
    rotational_acc_lim: 3.2

waypoint_follower parameters
waypoint_follower:
ros__parameters:
    /bond_disable_heartbeat_timeout: true
    use_sim_time: False
    loop_rate: 200
    stop_on_failure: false
    waypoint_task_executor_plugin: "wait_at_waypoint"
    wait_at_waypoint:
      plugin: "nav2_waypoint_follower::WaitAtWaypoint"
      enabled: True
      waypoint_pause_duration: 200

Any help would be really appreciated,
Thanks in advance
